# Do you think COVID-19 will affect paid internship opportunities?

Tags: job-search, recruitment, internship, covid-19

Right before the outbreak started, I got a paid internship from the government through my university. I'm supposed to find a company till the end of May but I'm worried that companies might not accept interns in light of a recession.

Do you think this will affect the process of finding a company and if so, what are things I should look out for?

Comment: Yes, it most likely will. What did you study? In what country is this in? Why are you asking us? Try finding an internship now. Nothing beats action. If you find nothing, at least you will have tried. Also, even if you find nothing, you won't be alone.

Comment: Some companies are closing / being closed by the government until further notice... so if they are shut do you think they will need an intern?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I am studying Computer Science in Greece. Thanks for the advice! I'll start mailing first thing tomorrow.

Comment: @SolarMike I see your point. I'd like to think that by the time that the internship is to start, the companies that will endure the global recession will be sorted out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**YES, In short COVID-19 is going in to affect everything.**

But it may not be all doom and gloom, some companies may actually turn to interns rather than full time hires as a cost cutting exercise until they are operating at levels pre-COVID.

Every person and company will feel the effects differently, there will actually be some sectors that benefit financially form this crisis, but not as many that will lose out.

Comment: I see what you mean. I should then aim for companies in industries that where the least affected by the virus, or have had a positive net gain due to the virus.

Answer (score 0):

Covid 19 is not the first tragedy the world has ever witnessed, at the time of panic and emergency certain questions of our busy mind become useless and annoying as a result we are overwhelmed by fear and feeling of despair.

Before the outbreak if you had planned to complete your studies, secure a paid internship and then a full time job you don't have to worry for the future if our present is at stake. The novel-covid has affected the globe. There are people in present who have lost their jobs and some are lying on the beds in the hospitals, but certainly such a situation shall not prevail.

Global Reccession is a disaster for a time being, there will be no effect on the paid interships are such practices are done globally and it has its own niches.

Due to outbreak money flow in the market has stopped as a result there is a peak growing in peoples and business investments savings. in this situation everything will recover smoothly once the market resumes.

Internet is full of opportunities and if you search it you will eventually get it.